# How to query field containing any of the strings in the array

Tags: mongodb

There are plenty of answers on StackOverflow on how to query a field that contains a particular string.

However, how would you write a query that finds results where field is matching any of the strings in the array?

For example, query array is `["win","success","goal"]`

and it will match results such as:

`{someProperty: "this was a win"},{someProperty: "our goal is"},{someProperty: "successfully completed"}`

Comment: You mean `.find({ "array.someProperty": /win|success|goal/ })`. Because I'm pretty sure there are plenty of answers that say that one as well. Or even `.find({ "array.someProperty": { "$in": [/win/,/success/,/goal/] } })`. You are basically asking to "match a string within a string", which is a "regular expression". MongoDB does not care less if it's a single field or an array, just as long as you point it at the correct path.

Comment: the $in way doesn't seem work because it expects the property value to be a substring of the query value rather than the other way round.

Comment: Works for the rest of us. But I'm not sure what you are doing. I'm presuming in all cases that your "array" is named "array" and contains documents with `"someProperty"` just as defined in the question. It's not like I don't have loads of code that already does this.

Comment: i'm querying mongo database, not searching through an array object.

Comment: Then simply `"someProperty"`. It's the same answer either way, and even more directly related to the original answer that it is linked to. This is not an uncommon thing. Which is why there is already and existing answer. Possibly more.